# JavaScript: How to split string into array based on a curly-braces-pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split a string similar to this:

```
"2*{some_string}*8*{some_other_string}"
```

Into an array, keeping the curly braces intact:

```
["2*","{some_string}","*8*","{some_other_string}"]
```

I'm hitting a wall and always end up remove the curly braces. Any clues out there?

I've been working with something like this:

```
var found = [],          // an array to collect the strings that are found
    rxp = /{([^}]+)}/g,
    str = "a {string} with {curly} braces",
    curMatch;

while( curMatch = rxp.exec( str ) ) {
    found.push( curMatch[1] );
}

console.log( found );    // ["string", "curly"]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: what have you tried so far ? please post the code

Comment: Updated my post above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't really need replace. You can keep the {} when you split it by using regex, but it will create empty string, so you will need to use filter to remove empty string in the array after splitting.

```js
console.log("2*{some_string}*8*{some_other_string}".split(/({.*?})/).filter(s => !!s))
```